# Preventing the copy function from adding a <tab> when copying text in a <TD>

Tags: html, google-chrome, copy

I find that if I'm copying text from a web page and the text is inside of a table cell, it's common that a tab will be pre-pended to the copied text.

Example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>I want to copy this</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I copy and paste elsewhere, I get:

```
      I want to copy this
```

Is there any effective strategy for preventing that from happening?

Answer (score -4):

You can paste it into, a plaintext editor or into your URL bar to remove weird encoding and then re-paste it where ever its ultimate destination will be. Also this isn't much of an html question.

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting it using Ctrl+c => Ctrl+v - try using Ctrl+c => Ctrl+Shift+v - it works on Windows. Mac and Linux - I don´t know.